# SCNetworkReachabilityFlags Redefinition?

Tags: ios, xcode7, redefinition

I upgraded XCode7 and there is an error with SystemConfiguration.framework

[image]

How do I solve?
thx!

Comment: Did you try to remove all derived data and clean the project? (product -> clean; windows -> projects -> find project -> remove derived data)

Comment: thx for u ask . I tried, but it's no use